# Проблема с регулярными выражениями

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Я хочу вырезать текст из строки с помощью регулярных выражений.
Я использую регулярное выражение:

```
(([0-9]+)\s+метров|([0-9]+)м)
```

Если им обработать строку `"Типа 10 метров"`, он вырезает `"10 метров"`, а не `"10"`

P.S. Я использую метод `group()`

Comment: На каком языке написано?

Comment: Укажите язык программирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы использовал [позитивный просмотр вперёд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4)

Для php сработает такой вариант (с java не работал):

```
/(\d+)(?=м\b|\s+метров)/
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/sH6dD9/2

P.S. И полное совпадение и первая группа содержат только цифры.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня сработал, теперь регулярные выражения не буду засорять

Answer (score 1):

Перепишите запрос в таком виде:

```
([0-9]+)(\s+метров|м)
```

Comment: Возвращает тоже самое

Comment: @NeoKat Возвращает где ? полное совпадение выражение конечно с метрами, но первая группа захвата (первые скобки) дают именно 10. https://regex101.com/r/kH5qW5/1  А вот как получить первую группу захвата - это зависит от языка на котором пишите

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает (язык в тегах указать забыл, если что, Java)